# Qt: mouse cursor flickering due to fast screen sampling

Tags: c++, winapi, qt5, qthread

Hello i use this code to quickly (about 60 times/second) sample the screen and find its average color:

```c++
samplerWorker::samplerWorker(int newId)
{
    this->id = newId;
    this->screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
    this->screenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    this->hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    this->hDesktopDC = GetDC(this->hDesktopWnd);
    this->hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(this->hDesktopDC);
}

void samplerWorker::sampleAvgColor(int workerId)
{
    if(workerId != this->id)
    {
        return;
    }
    HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(this->hDesktopDC, this->screenWidth, this->screenHeight);
    SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap);

    BitBlt(this->hCaptureDC, 0, 0, this->screenWidth, this->screenHeight, this->hDesktopDC, 0,0, SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);

    BITMAPINFO bmi = {0};
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = this->screenWidth;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = this->screenHeight;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    int size = this->screenWidth * this->screenHeight * 4;
    unsigned char *pPixels = new unsigned char[size];

    GetDIBits(this->hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap, 0, this->screenHeight, pPixels, &bmi,    DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    unsigned int avgR = 0;
    unsigned int avgG = 0;
    unsigned int avgB = 0;
    size = size /4;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        avgB = avgB + pPixels[4*i + 0];
        avgG = avgG + pPixels[4*i + 1];
        avgR = avgR + pPixels[4*i + 2];
    }

    avgR = avgR / (size);
    avgG = avgG / (size);
    avgB = avgB / (size);

    emit returnAvgColor(avgR,avgG,avgB);

    delete[] pPixels;

    DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);
}
```

samplerWorker is an object that works in a few separate threads, each samplerWorker is in a separate thread, and they are called one after another, so first screenshot is taken by samplerWorker with id == 0, then id == 1, and so on until all of them are called and then it returns back to sampler worker with id == 0. But for some reason, when i screenshot my screen fast enough (more than 10-15 fps) my cursor starts flickering. What might cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer: [Raymond Chen Discusses the Case of the Disappearing Cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/technet-magazine/dd392008(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

> These translucent windows, known as layered windows, are not normally
> included by the BitBlt function when reading pixels from the screen.
> In order to get them, you have to pass the CAPTUREBLT flag.
>
> The mouse cursor is just another composition object and therefore
> would be captured by the CAPTUREBLT flag. To prevent this from
> happening during a screen capture, the composition engine has to hide
> the cursor, do the CAPTUREBLT, and then re-show the cursor.

Related case: [Cursor disappears on bitblt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229271/cursor-disappears-on-bitblt)

Comment: @Артем Налькин Hi, if the answer is useful to you, don't forget to mark it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)